# Idea complains about valid typescript code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, intellij-idea

I try to write my first angular 2 hello world application.

I have the following project structure:
[image]

I see a lot if errors in editor altgough code works properly.

Error texts:

cannot compile modules unless the `--module` flag is provided
Decorators are only available when targeting ecmascript 5 and higher.

I searching in configuration and see only following:

[image]

Please help to avoid errors.

ts.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The errors seems pretty straight forward..  Can you share your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc-e2e",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: What happens if you try to compile it yourself using `tsc`? Something like: `tsc -p ./`

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer where should I write this code?

Comment: In the console/terminal. In the same directory where your `tsconfig.json` is located

Comment: @ Nitzan Tomer D:\javaScript\untitled\angular2-todo-app\node_modules\tsconfig\dist>tsc -p ./
'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Nitzan Tomer  D:\javaScript\untitled\angular2-todo-app\node_modules\tsconfig\dist>where tsc
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

Comment: Seems like you haven't installed typescript globally. If you installed it locally then it should be in the `node_modules` so: `../../typescript/bin/tsc -p ./`. If you have installed typescript then first install it: `npm install typescript` or `npm install -g typescript` and then try it